# Trigger to track all the insert or update on Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle table as below -

MasterTable:

```
ID      columnA    columnB   columnC   columnD
1234      Dan       Smith    12C      Stanford
1233      Raj       Desai    04L      New York
1232      Will      Scot     26D      Dallas
1231      Dean      White    35S      Atlanta
```

I want to write a trigger on Master table whenever any insert or update happens on Master table those changes will be inserted into Audit table.

e.g. if ID 1234 is updated or inserted then changes should be inserted as below

entryID, Log_id which is updated/inserted, datetime of change, column name which is updated/inserted and new value of the column as below

AuditTable:

```
EntryID  Log_id  datetime             CloumnName     value
1        1234    20190815:06:12:50     ColumnA       Dan
2        1234    20190815:02:12:50     columnD       Stanford
3        1231    20190814:09:12:50     coulmnB       White
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would test each column separately and insert that:

```
insert into audittable (log_id, datetime, columnname, value)
    select :new.id, sysdate, 'ColumnA', :new.columnA
    from dual
    where :new.columnA <> :old.columnA or
          (:new.ColumnA is null and :old.columnA is not null) or
          (:new.ColumnA is not null and :old.columnA is null);
```

Then repeat this for each column you want to check.